# Using AWS S3 & CloudFront to steam videos from my website is a 403 forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-403

I want to store videos in an Amazon S3 bucket.
I want to load them onto my website.
I want to use Amazon CloudFront for the CDN/caching etc.

Ideally by the end I would like to restrict the videos to only play on the domains I set.

But initially I am having a 403 error even loading the video.

It says in console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

And clicking it shows this XML

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>9PW32M02SZR567DF</RequestId>
    <HostId>ukPRxDlFq9TYiJcHLnnAhryAewPoAd/ijm/GxHvdB774cMwK4PdQ0yr1CQqa1msCV+CkYj+nkL0=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have tried many things after much reading.

Initially, I had set up the distribution with a key and I believe using OAI.

I have now disabled the WAF part of it to try and rule out that as a variable.

I am loading the video directly in the browser.  At one point a video player loaded but the video itself did not.

I created public keys

I created key groups

I selected my S3 bucket in CloudFront so I could not have made a typo.

I created an "origin access" and I have tried with both signing and not signing the request.

I set up Identities (legacy)

I have disabled encryption and bucket key.

All public access is blocked.

I copied the permissions from CloudFront and added it to the S3 bucket's permissions.

This is my bucket policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::tpwc-co-uk--media/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::240479180938:distribution/E17GLPD7918NNC"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Server side encryption is set as:

`Server-side encryption with Amazon S3 managed keys (SSE-S3)`

Here is my URL if that helps: https://d2tzr0xka0eqcu.cloudfront.net

By making my S3 bucket publicly available I can see the URL via S3, but the CloudFront URL still doesn't work.

I updated my policy to include `getObject`.  My S3 bucket policy now stands as:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::tpwc-co-uk--media/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::240479180938:distribution/E17GLPD7918NNC"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::tpwc-co-uk--media/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

## Screenshots

Here are screenshots of the things I have configured.  Any missing screenshots means no configuration has taken place.

### Distribution Screenshots

#### General

[image: General]

#### Settings

[image: Settings]

#### Origin Settings

[image: Origin]

### Bucket Screenshots

#### Permissions

[image: Permissions]

#### Management

[image: Management]

#### Encryption

[image: Ecryption]

Can anyone help me to understand where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Block Public Access setting may be the problem.
Suggesting to try these steps.

1 - S3 bucket which stores the video should configured as a static website, ensure block public access setting is OFF.

2 - Create a S3 bucket policy that gives S3:GetObject permission to *

3 - Test that it works first.

4 - In Cloudfront set the S3 bucket as a custom origin

5 - In Cloudfront configure an Origin Access Control - AWS will generate a Origin Access policy. Copy it.

6 - Go to the S3 Bucket and edit the policy to only allow the OAI to access (paste the policy)

7 - Back in CloudFront configure a Behaviour so that a request for the bucket is sent.

Path pattern : /*.mp4 (example)
Origin : Pick the origin created in step 4.

Hope that worked for you.

Here is an update with sample screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Ok I did up to step 3 and that worked.  Although I didn't do 1 and it still worked.  The thing is I am not hosting a static website and I do not have an index.html.  I am hosting a dynamic website elsewhere, I just want to use AWS for the video storage and CloudFront for the CDN.  I can just add a blank index.html that won't be an issue I just want to be sure I'm doing the right thing.  That's the same reason I didn't really want it to be public, I thought having CloudFront access the site avoided the need for it to be public.

Comment: I can access the file without it being seen as a static website.  So what is the difference between having it as a static website and not having it as a static website, aside from the index.html?  Is there a pricing difference or anything like that?

Comment: CloudFront doesn't let me edit the path pattern it's just `"Default (*)"`.  Although that's fine for now whilst I try to get it working.

Comment: I can confirm that if I make the bucket publicly accessible via S3 I can still not access it via my CloudFront link.  There is some permissions issue there, so we are narrowing things down.  Thanks for the help so far it was useful and helped me move forwards.

Comment: I think your CloudFront distribution, OAC is configured properly
Same for your S3 bucket, it grants access to the CloudFront OAC and has turned OFF Block Public access.
Test the CloudFront url like this: append the name of your video file.

https://d2tzr0xka0eqcu.cloudfront.net/video.mp4

Your S3 bucket policy is overly permissive, update it after tests are done.

Going forward, once it works
ADD a custom origin to CloudFront for your dynamic content 
ADD a behaviour to redirect static content requests to S3.

If it still doesnt work, there may be a permissions boundary in effect.

Comment: Ah ok, I was testing it wrong.  But then this should work: https://d2tzr0xka0eqcu.cloudfront.net/2023.01.23_tpwc_ambulance_chasing_v4%20(Original).mp4 but it's still forbidden.

Comment: I asked someone else to have a look.  Which I always think is a good solution.  Because as soon as I showed them the URL that wasn't working.... it worked.  Of course it did.  Must have been caching or something.

Comment: I ended up making the bucket public, which I wasn't sure was right or not.  Afterall I would want the public to view the images, but there again, I thought the point in CloudFront was to avoid it having to be public.  Anyway it's working now.  I removed the policy and used the other option.  Question Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way or the best way, but someone helped me and it now works, so that is progress.

In the end I also wanted to access to the bucket remotely to upload/download/etc files within Joomla using [Akeeba S3 File system](https://github.com/akeeba/plg_filesystem_s3).  So perhaps that had an influence on why the person helped me configure it this way.  I'm just leaving it here for both myself and future users in case they have this issue.

To be clear, the other answer worked which is why I marked it as correct.

## My new S3 bucket settings

Rather than using the policy, I used another option which stops the policy being used.

[image: My new S3 bucket settings]

I edited **Object Ownership** and changed it to **ACL's enabled**.

Once I had done this my policy was no longer being used and instead the access control I was using instead.

[image: ACL Settings]

Once I had done this I then had to go to the **Access Control List Settings**.

[image: Access Control List Settings]

I only had to enable one thing, I had to tick the box for **list** under "**Everyone, public access group**" and then save it.

Initially, it would not let me tick this box and said I didn't have access privileges to do so.  To get that to work I had to change the "**block public access**" setting and **untick everything**.